Issues connecting TP-Link between TV and Asus router/switch on home network. Is this an ARP storm?
My Asus router/switch began to reboot itself every 30 seconds the other day (nothing changed in terms of devices on the network).
After countless reboots/resets, I disconnected everything and reconnected everything one by one. I found out that the problem arises when I connect any device to my TP-Link switch that is connected to the Asus router/switch. So my setup is very simple:
---------            ----------
| Asus  |            |TPLink   |               
|Switch/| -----------|Switch   |------------- TV/Laptop/PC etc.
|Router |            |         |
---------            -----------

If I connect my TV (or any other device) to Asus switch then everything works. If the same TV or any other device is connected to my network via TP-Link switch I get the following packets (192.168.24.1 is the default gateway and 192.168.24.141 is the TV):

I get a lot of ARP broadcasts. Is this ARP storm? My setup when getting these packets is one cable running from Asus to TPLink and one cable running from TP-Link to TV, nothing more. How can there be a loop?
First I thought it was the TP-Link failing, because I don't get this problem when TV is connected to Asus. So I replaced TP-Link switch with a MikroTik AP, but the same ARP broadcasts happened.
Maybe this is a simple problem, but as I am a network rookie I don't know where to go from here, as I don't understand what might be causing these repetitive ARP broadcasts.

Update: Although things seem to be working after changing switch IP to static and back to dynamic, the switch is not displayed in router DHCP lease list. The IP for the switch is 192.168.25.196 and I can access its user interface while being connected to Asus, but it does not show up in this list. Last time I saw it was when things started to work again.




192.168.24.141 continues to ARP due to it is not receiving a response.

Broken cable? Response not possible due to that?

Tried replacing cables but nothing. Did a firmware update on the TPLink switch and at least the router stopped rebooting, but still no ARP response. Also tried to access router admin interface while being connected to TPLink switch and as Zac67 said, the switch was like offline, couldn't access the router. Then I changed the switch IP to static, but that didn't help. Then when changing it back to dynamic, voila the switch came back to life and TV was connected. Glad it is working, but I'm not sure what the problem was. As far as I know, the settings are back as they were when problems started.

Where/how did you capture that traffic? Any idea of what the previous dynamic IP of the switch was? What are the references of the switch and router?

Welcome to the site - that's some great troubleshooting to start with, thank you.

Does the TV have DHCP enabled or is it statically configured?   What model is the TPLINK switch- is it just a switch or is it a router too?   Where is 192.168.24.179 connected in the network and can it see the default gateway ?

@jcaron this traffic was captured with my laptop being connected to Asus device. I don't know the previous IP for the switch. Criggie, TV has DHCP enabled. TPLink model is TL-SG108E and it is switch only. I believe 192.168.24.179 was my Laptop, which was connected to Asus.

The fact that we do not see a response does not mean there wasn’t one: the ARP requests are broadcast (so any device I closing your laptop will have received them), the ARP response can be targeted to be sent only to the device which requested it, and since it just requested it it’s in forwarding tables, so it will be sent only to the right ports and not to the one your laptop is connected to. So we don’t know if it was the router not replying or the TV not receiving it. I’m not sure we will ever know…

As for the switch not appearing in the DHCP list, if you last turned the router on after the switch, it’s possible the switch is still using its previous lease and did not ask the router again since the router rebooted. Or the switch is configured with a static IP (hopefully outside the DHCP pool, but that does not seem to be the case). Or you have another device acting as a DHCP server and that is wreaking havoc on your network.

That's not an ARP storm. The frequency indicated (~1 Hz) tells us it's just your TV desperately looking for its default gateway. Apparently, connectivity to the router is broken. An ARP storm would run at >10 Hz.
Judging from your description, the switch isn't working properly or the router is effectively offline. What causes the router reboots you are seeing, I can't say. Does the switch work between two hosts (you need manually configured IP addresses without a DHCP server)? At any port?
A constantly rebooting router may indicate a firmware bug (look at the vendor's support page for the current version) - perhaps a newly connected device on the switch triggers that bug -, or failing hardware. Remove all devices from the switch and connect one by one.

Yes, if this were an arp storm there would also be many, many more broadcast packets.
